Neural network that augments the input with constants
Suppose we have a simple neural network as follows:
f = NetChain[
  {
    LinearLayer[32],
    ElementwiseLayer["ReLU"],
    LinearLayer[16],
    ElementwiseLayer["ReLU"],
    LinearLayer[1]
  },
  "Input" -> 3,
  "Output" -> 1
]

How can we represent the function g as a neural network that behaves like the function below?
g[v_] := Max@Map[f[Append[v, #]] &, Range[10000]]


Here is one possible solution in case someone has a similar question.
op = NetGraph[
  <|
    "f" -> f,
    "cat" -> CatenateLayer[]
  |>,
  {
    {NetPort["Input1"], NetPort["Input2"]} -> "cat" -> "f" -> NetPort["Output"]
  }
]

g = NetGraph[
  <|
    "repl" -> ReplicateLayer[10000],
    "const" -> NetArrayLayer["Array" -> Transpose[{Range[10000]}], "LearningRateMultipliers" -> None],
    "mapthread" -> NetMapThreadOperator[op],
    "max" -> AggregationLayer[Max, All]
  |>,
  {
    NetPort["Input"] -> "repl" -> "mapthread",
    "const" -> "mapthread" -> "max" -> NetPort["Output"]
  }
]

